# checkbox from controller Codeigniter not show in datatables ajax call

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, datatables

I have little problem on my code.

I have code to show data in datatables and in my first column I want to show checkbox select. My datatables was created by ajax call and controller in Codeigniter. But when I load the code, checkbox not show, but eachother column can show.

This is My code

My Controller

```
function data_schedule_emp()
{

    $draw       = intval($this->input->get("draw"));
    $start      = intval($this->input->get("start"));
    $length     = intval($this->input->get("length"));
    $year       = $this->input->post("year");
    $month      = $this->input->post("month");
    $dept       = $this->input->post("dept");
    $pos        = $this->input->post("pos");
    $date_slct  = $year.'-'.$month.'-';
    $shifts     = $this->m_general->get_data('tb_shift')->result();
    $rows       = $this->m_employee->list_schedule_emp($date_slct)->result();
    if($dept=='99'){
        if($pos=='ALL'){
            $pin_emp    = $this->m_employee->get_detail_emp()->result();
        }else{
            $pin_emp    = $this->m_employee->get_detail_emp($pos)->result();
        }
    }else{
        if($pos=='ALL'){
            $pin_emp    = $this->m_employee->get_detail_emp($dept)->result();
        }else{
            $pin_emp    = $this->m_employee->get_detail_emp($dept,$pos)->result();
        }
    }
    $total_days = tglakhir($year,$month);
    $data       = array();
    $no         = 1;
    $all_data   = array();
    $array_pin  = array();
    $row        = array();
    $date       = array();

    foreach ($rows as $row) {
            // this may seem convoluted, take your time to understand
            $people[$row->date][$row->id_nip] = $row;
        }

    foreach($pin_emp AS $q)
        {
            $array_pin[]=$q->emp_pin;
            $details[$q->emp_pin] = $q;
        }
    foreach($shifts AS $shift_e){
            $array_shift[$shift_e->id_shift] = $shift_e;
        }
    for($m=1; $m <= $total_days; $m++){
            if($m<10){
            $m = '0'.$m;
            }else{
                $m = $m;
            }
            $dates[]=$m;
        }
    foreach ($array_pin AS $pin){
        $x=$bg=$n_shift='';
        $date_range = array();
        $n_shift        = $details[$pin]->emp_shift;
        foreach ($dates as $date) {
            $x_shift = $n_shift;
            $full_date = $year.'-'.$month.'-'.$date;
            $day = date('D', strtotime($full_date));
            if(($n_shift==1) && ($day=='Fri')){
                $x_shift=2;
            }if(($day == 'Sun') OR ($day == 'Sat')){
                $x_shift=13;
            }
            $bg     = $array_shift[$x_shift]->background;
            $label  = $array_shift[$x_shift]->code_shift;
            $note   = $array_shift[$x_shift]->note;
            $x='<a class="btn '.$bg.' btn-xs" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="'.$note.'">'.$label.'</a>';
            $check='<input type="checkbox">';
            if(isset($people[$full_date][$pin]->id_shift_emp)==TRUE){
                $get_shift  = $people[$full_date][$pin]->id_shift_emp;
                $code_shift = $people[$full_date][$pin]->code_shift;
                $bg         = $array_shift[$get_shift]->background;
                $label      = $array_shift[$get_shift]->code_shift;
                $note       = $array_shift[$get_shift]->note;
                $x='<a class="btn '.$bg.' btn-xs" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="'.$note.'>'.$code_shift.'</a>';
            }
            $date_range[]=$x;
        }
        $data = array(
            $check,
            $pin,
            $details[$pin]->emp_name
        );
        $no++;
    $all_data[]=array_merge($data,$date_range);
    }

    $output = array(
            "draw" => $draw,
            "recordsTotal" => $rows,
            "recordsFiltered" => $rows,
            "data" => $all_data
        );
    echo json_encode($output);
}
```

This my ajax call

```
$('#list_schedule_emp').dataTable({
        "ajax": {
            "url": base_url+'employee/data_schedule_emp',
            "type": "POST",
            "data": {
                "year": $('#year').val(),
                "month": $('#month').val(),
                "dept": $('#dept').val(),
                "pos": $('#pos').val()
            }
        },
        "className": 'select-checkbox',
        drawCallback: function() {
            $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
                container: 'body'
            });
        }
    });
```

and this My View

```
<div class="table-responsive">
                <input type="hidden" name="year" id="year" value="<?php echo $year; ?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="month" id="month" value="<?php echo $month; ?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="dept" id="dept" value="<?php echo $dept; ?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="pos" id="pos" value="<?php echo $pos; ?>">
                <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover" id="list_schedule_emp">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Select</th>
                            <th>Pin</th>
                            <th>Nama</th>
                            <?php foreach ($date_range AS $date) { ?>
                                <th><?php echo $date ?></th>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
```

Where My mistake? Please show me.

Thanks All.

[image]

Comment: Have you verified the output `json_encode($output)` Does it have checkbox input?

Comment: mr @mPareek yes i have verified check output and it's have, just not shown. I have check by Firefox Web Developer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Datatables provides functionality for automatically adding a checkbox as the first column, see [the docs](https://datatables.net/extensions/select/examples/initialisation/checkbox.html)
or [this similar question on their forums](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/48650/add-a-checkbox-as-a-first-column#Comment_128034)

Essentially, droping all the checkbox creation from your data completely and changing your initialization code to something like the below should work.

#### NOTE

You havent told us the version of datatables you're using and their api has changed in many subtle ways over the years so you may need to tweak this example by reading the related docs for your specific version.

```
$('#list_schedule_emp').dataTable({
    "ajax": {
        "url": base_url+'employee/data_schedule_emp',
        "type": "POST",
        "data": {
            "year": $('#year').val(),
            "month": $('#month').val(),
            "dept": $('#dept').val(),
            "pos": $('#pos').val()
        }
    },
    drawCallback: function() {
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
            container: 'body'
        });
    }
    columnDefs: [ {
        orderable: false,
        className: 'select-checkbox',
        targets:   0
    } ],
    select: {
        style:    'os',
        selector: 'td:first-child'
    },
    order: [[ 1, 'asc' ]],
});
```

Comment: Hello mr. @WesleySmith, I'm using DataTables 1.10.12.  I have tried your example and still not work. maybe need to update version datatables?

Comment: @MardinoIsmail Hmm, Im not sure, that version should support this feature and here's another article showing the same thing with a slightly different approach maybe try that: https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-how-to-add-a-checkbox-column/